# Join video in FFmpeg have problem More than 1000 frames duplicated

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Hello I have this FFMPEG code

```
ffmpeg -i video1.mp4 -i video2.mp4 -i video3.mp4 -filter_complex 
"[0:v]scale=1280x720,setsar=1[v0];
[1:v]scale=1280x720,setsar=1[v1];
[2:v]scale=1280x720,setsar=1[v2]; 
[v0][0:a][v1][1:a][v2][2:a]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1" output.mp4
```

But I exec it it give back me this Warring Message:

> More than 1000 frames duplicated

How can I solve it? Plesase help me. Thanks!

Comment: If playback is fine, you can ignore it.

Comment: What do you mean? @Gyan